# Why CMake removes the gcc 4.9.x colors?

Tags: gcc, cmake

Since version 4.9 `gcc` can finally shows a coloured output like `clang` does. No more wrapper scripts are required.
I have the following line in my `.bashrc`:

```
export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
```

and the colors are there when invoking `gcc` itself (*without* using the flag -`fdiagnostics-color`)

However, the same is not true if `gcc` is called by a `CMake`-generated `Makefile`. For some reason all the gcc colors are always removed, while cmake preserves the clang colors.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I ran your `export` and built with `CMake` and my `gcc` 4.9 built with colored warnings. If you run `export` with no parameters, it should tell you what's been exported. Verify that `GCC_COLORS` is listed, correctly capitalized, and correctly formatted (parseable). Lastly, try adding `-fdiagnostics-color` to your `CMakeLists.txt` anyway.

Comment: @inetknght My `export` output has the following line: `declare -x GCC_COLORS="error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01"`. So, the variable seems ok. I'll try adding the flag to `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

I was running `sudo make install` and in the root environment there was no `GCC_COLORS` variable defined. That's why the gcc colors were gone while the clang ones were showed.

Running `make install` with user privileges shows the gcc colors as expected.
Sorry for the useless question.